# create master database service with sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, master-data-services

I could not create database with master data service of SQL Server 2008 R2, I get this error:

```
The specified SQL Server instance do not support master dataservice database the
edition lavel is not supported connecte to another SQL Server instance.
```

Have you got any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You have to be using 1 of the following editions of SQL 2008r2...

SQL Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise
SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633742%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).